# Excluding a dependency in pip-audit

Tags: python, pip

I have a `pipenv` project that is using the Trend Micro `deepsecurity` dependency.  Up until recently, this was available on pypi, but Trend has since removed it.  They require one to download the SDK and install it manually.  Not a horrible issue, as I unzip the package and `pip install` it.

```bash
pip freeze|grep deep                                     1 ✘  4s  portal-bVWoHG0U  

deep-security-api @ file:///Users/paul/src/smartronix/portal/ds_temp
```

Unfortunately, this causes heartburn for pip-audit:

```bash
> pip-audit                                                     ✔  5s  portal-

Traceback (most recent call last):                    
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/bin/pip-audit", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(audit())
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_cli.py", line 370, in audit
    for (spec, vulns) in auditor.audit(source):
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_audit.py", line 66, in audit
    for dep, vulns in self._service.query_all(specs):
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_service/interface.py", line 143, in query_all
    yield self.query(spec)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_service/pypi.py", line 58, in query
    response: requests.Response = self.session.get(url=url, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 667, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 667, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 166, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded {} redirects.'.format(self.max_redirects), response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

The reason for this (as fully documented below) is that pypi used to know about deep security, but has it no longer and provides a confusing response.  I'd like to simply exclude this dependency but can't see how to do it.

### Verbose pip-audit run

```bash
pip-audit -v                                                

DEBUG:pip_audit._cli:parsed arguments: Namespace(cache_dir=None, desc=<VulnerabilityDescriptionChoice.Auto: 'auto'>, dry_run=False, extra_index_urls=[], fix=False, format=<OutputFormatChoice.Columns: 'columns'>, index_url='https://pypi.org/simple', local=False, output=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, paths=[], progress_spinner=<ProgressSpinnerChoice.On: 'on'>, project_path=None, require_hashes=False, requirements=None, skip_editable=False, strict=False, timeout=15, verbose=True, vulnerability_service=<VulnerabilityServiceChoice.Pypi: 'pypi'>)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/alembic/1.7.7/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/alembic/1.7.7/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/aniso8601/9.0.1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/aniso8601/9.0.1/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/apscheduler/3.9.1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/APScheduler/3.9.1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/APScheduler/3.9.1/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/astroid/2.6.6/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/astroid/2.6.6/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/atomicwrites/1.4.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/atomicwrites/1.4.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/attrs/21.4.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/attrs/21.4.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/autopep8/1.6.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/autopep8/1.6.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-common/1.1.28/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-common/1.1.28/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-core/1.24.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-core/1.24.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-identity/1.11.0b1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-identity/1.11.0b1/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-compute/26.1.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-mgmt-compute/26.1.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-core/1.3.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-mgmt-core/1.3.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-loganalytics/13.0.0b4/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-mgmt-loganalytics/13.0.0b4/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-recoveryservices/2.0.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-mgmt-recoveryservices/2.0.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup/4.2.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup/4.2.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-mgmt-resource/21.1.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-mgmt-resource/21.1.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/azure-monitor-query/1.0.2/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/azure-monitor-query/1.0.2/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/backports-zoneinfo/0.2.1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/backports.zoneinfo/0.2.1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/backports.zoneinfo/0.2.1/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.2.2/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/bcrypt/3.2.2/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/black/22.3.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/black/22.3.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/boto3/1.22.13/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/boto3/1.22.13/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/botocore/1.25.13/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/botocore/1.25.13/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/cachecontrol/0.12.11/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/CacheControl/0.12.11/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/CacheControl/0.12.11/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/certifi/2021.10.8/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/certifi/2021.10.8/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/cffi/1.15.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7238
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/cffi/1.15.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/cfgv/3.3.1/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/cfgv/3.3.1/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/charset-normalizer/2.0.12/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/charset-normalizer/2.0.12/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/click/8.1.3/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/click/8.1.3/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/coverage/6.3.3/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/coverage/6.3.3/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/cryptography/37.0.2/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/cryptography/37.0.2/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/cyclonedx-python-lib/2.3.0/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Current age based on date: 7237
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Freshness lifetime from max-age: 900
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/cyclonedx-python-lib/2.3.0/json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json/" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/deep-security-api/12.0.466/json" in the cache
DEBUG:cachecontrol.controller:Returning cached permanent redirect response (ignoring date and etag information)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/bin/pip-audit", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(audit())
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_cli.py", line 370, in audit
    for (spec, vulns) in auditor.audit(source):
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_audit.py", line 66, in audit
    for dep, vulns in self._service.query_all(specs):
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_service/interface.py", line 143, in query_all
    yield self.query(spec)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip_audit/_service/pypi.py", line 58, in query
    response: requests.Response = self.session.get(url=url, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 667, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 667, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "/Users/paul/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-bVWoHG0U/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 166, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded {} redirects.'.format(self.max_redirects), response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did find a real solution to the problem, but I did make this workaround; just delete deepsecurity!  For reference, here is the script that I use in my CI pipeline

```
set -e
# Remove trend deep security, as it causes pip-audit to fail
pipenv run pip uninstall -y deep-security-api
pipenv run pip-audit
```